# Java Exception when Trying to Run Grails

Tags: java, grails, windows-7

All - I just downloaded the latest grails (2.1.0) and JDK (1.7.0_07) on my Win7 64bit machine and configured my machine as follows:

1.) Added environment variables for Java and Grails
2.) Update PATH as appropriate
3.) Verified that everything installed correctly by executing `java -version` and `grails -version`

The `java -version` command works, and shows the following:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

but the `grails -version` command yields the following error:

```
Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread “main”
```

I tried debugging by completely uninstalling all Java, then reinstalling, but the same error occurs. I verified that I installed the 64 bit version of Java.

More information about the error can be found at [this website](http://www.grailsexample.net/installing-a-grails-development-environment-on-windows/#comment-5225) (Mike [the owner] directed me to Stackoverflow for more help).

Any idea is to why this occurred? What can I do to get Grails working? Thanks in advance for your help.

-Tom

**Edit 1** from Vector's comment:

All variables are set properly and shown here:

```
GRAILS_HOME = C:\grails\grails-2.1.0 
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07 
Path = [lots of other stuff];%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;
```

**Edit 2** Fixed java version number at top of problem statement (version is 1.7.0_07) per @crudolf

Comment: ... have you verified that Groovy path is set?

Comment: Yes. Here are all my variables:  
    GRAILS_HOME = C:\grails\grails-2.1.0  
    JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07  
    Path = [lots of other stuff];%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;

Comment: Are you sure, that 1.7.0_07 is the version you have installed? In the first sentence you talk about 1.7.0_17 but your path use 1.7.0_07.

Comment: Double check your PATH variable.. maybe you have a JRE installed in your path. Try to enter `javac`.

Comment: @crudolf What is shown in the code is correct (I must have copied incorrectly from above). Fixed in main body of text.

I typed javac -version and got "javac 1.7.0_07". Is that what you mean?

Comment: can you double check your grails installation? try `grails-debug` and `startGrails` from console.

Comment: @crudolf I downloaded Eclipse v3.0.0 (Groovy/Grails 64bit) and installed. I was able to create an app from Eclipse and run it with expected results (standard Grails homepage). Unfortunately, Grails still does not work in the command line. I tried running `grails-debug` and `startGrails`, but both commands were not found by Eclipse.

Comment: When grails is working from eclipse, your path or your grails installation is incorrupt. Check what jdk and grails installation is configured in your STS. I bet you have a 32-bit jdk in your path, which is in your 64-bit program folder.

Comment: Wow . . . this is crazy: apparently, even though I have admin on my box, I needed to double click inside of the Administrator folder, have Win 7 say "you don't have access, are you sure you want to?", then click yes so that Grails could access C:\Users\Administrator\.grails and \.groovy.

Thanks to all for your help. I'll answer the question now

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Thou shalt ensurest that thine box is set to Administrator . . . *and the people rejoiced*.

Apparently, Grails wants to write to C:\Users\Administrator.grails and C:\Users\Administrator.groovy. Even though I had admin rights on my machine (since I successfully installed Java), I apparently needed to **click through into the Administrator folder** in order for the preferences to be written that I wanted to use JDK.

All is well. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error after attempting to upgrade from Grails 2.1.0 to Grails 2.2.1 on Windows 7.

I simply had to delete the `C:\User\%USERNAME%\.grails` and `C:\User\%USERNAME%\.groovy` folders created by and leftover from Grails 2.1.0.

It appeared that Grails was loading some leftover cached JARs or configuration files of `.grails` and `.groovy` instead of `%GRAILS_HOME%`.

It took hours, but I learned my lesson - delete ".grails" and ".groovy" before running a new version of Grails!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with Grails 2.4.0 and 2.2.4 on Windows 8.1 Pro.  I noticed that the problem did not occur if I ran the grails command in an administrator cmd-shell.  I then checked my Appdata\Local\Temp.  It turned out that the security setting for the temp folder needed to be changed.  After I gave Everyone the full access to Appdata\Local\Temp folder, the problem was solved.  But you may need to check the security setting often because some Windows Apps reset the security setting.

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem too. For some reason, that folder was set to "Read Only"; after I removed the "Read Only" flag it works fine. I didn't need to give Everyone full access.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I was having a working grails-2.2.4 with java-1.7.25 on a Windows 7 x86. But it suddenly stopped working today. I tried removing ~/.groovy and ~/.grails, but still got java.lang.RuntimeException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Finally, the problem was solved by removing ~/.m2 as well.

BTW, "set DEBUG=1" before starting "grails" in a Command Prompt will show the environment and parameters to launch Java.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem but in Ubuntu 12.04. I solved it by removing $GROOVY_HOME environment variable. If you also have $GROOVY_HOME variable try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the file `.grails_history` file located in your `%Home%` directory.
This worked for me on Windows 8.1